# SharePoint framework

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview

In this new Client Web Part model there would be no IFrames. It will be all cient side thing.

My question is, where would the server code reside which is needed to support this new client side web part. for e.g some server side custom json/xml is queried.

Will that code reside in provider hosted App for SharePoint ??

Answer (score 6):

SPFX webparts will not have any server side code and it is all written in Javascript/typescript with Calls made to SharePoint using REST API or using JSOM. But if you need to write some server side code for e.g.: query something from external database or for some other scenario, then you need to create an ODATA Rest WebAPI for it and consume it in your SPFX webpart .

Comment: True about what the webpart DOES, but not what it IS ..The SharePoint Server still Serves the webPart , it still is a Microsoft proprietary webPart and not a Web Component.

Comment: But you have to admire Microsoft for the Marketing... They sell React and NPM and Gulp and the lot; Technologies which we Web Developers have used for many years now to .Net gurus as "Hey, the future is bright, you can now write anything your want"  I wonder how many companies are going to hire ex .Net developers who just started in this Client Side game, and how many companies will distrust that Microsoft Account manager and check the market with developers who have been in this business for many years. - for us an endpoint is just another endpoint

Comment: This is an interesting point. Where i currently work we have experimented with .net,MVC devs to write provider hosted apps in 2013 and it works well especially if your architecture is more than just SharePoint (Many SP apps nowadays are more than just SP)

Comment: I have attended Google I/O and its clear for me now, WebComponents are the future.. Sorry SPFx, but you came in years too late